# How to move the original object after using the spin tool

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode

I'm learning how to make polar array in Blender. I saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2XGjjcks0o) video that, among the other methods, explains how to use the spin tool.

A very simple test:

1. create a base object, say a cylinder
2. move to the desired offset from the 3D cursor (i.e. X: 30 mm)
3. in tab mode, use the spin tool to create the polar array

[image]

How to change the initial offset?

Let's say I want to change it from X: 30 mm to 40 mm. If I grab the resulting object it moves all the copies. Instead I just want to move the original object, in other words I want to change the radius of the polar array.

Comment: If you want to modifier the original object after the spin, you should use either array modifier or a gn modifier instead of the spin tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spin tool only modifies the mesh once without any non-destructive control after the operation(besides regular Adjust Last Operation panel that is lost as soon as another operation is done). If you wish to be able to adjust the result later, you should use Array modifier in object offset mode with a rotated offset object:

[image]

Like indicated in the comments, Geometry Nodes can also be used.